# Upgrade Postgis 1.5 Geometry Column to 2.x that contains the SRID and Polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to upgrade a spatial databse from Postgis 1.5 to 2.2 using the HARD UPGRADE path defined at http://www.postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade

When I restore the database dump with `perl utils/postgis_restore.pl`, my geometry column is changing from

Postgis 1.5

```
SRID=900914;POLYGON((-77.040887447023 38.9953394588967,-77.0409178504355 38.9953090555891,-77.040948253848 38.9953090555891,-77.040948253848 38.9952989211532,-77.0409381193772 38.9952989211532,-77.0409077159647 38.9952685178456,-77.0408975814939 38.9952685178456,-77.040887447023 38.9952786522815,-77.0408671780814 38.9952583834098,-77.0408570436105 38.9952583834098,-77.0408266401981 38.9952279801022,-77.0408165057272 38.9952279801022,-77.0408063712564 38.9952381145381,-77.0408063712564 38.9952887867174,-77.0408266401981 38.9953090555891,-77.0408266401981 38.9953394588967,-77.040887447023 38.9953394588967),(-77.0408773125522 38.9953191900249,-77.0408671780814 38.9953293244608,-77.0408570436105 38.9953191900249,-77.0408570436105 38.9953090555891,-77.0408773125522 38.9952887867174,-77.040887447023 38.9952887867174,-77.0408975814939 38.9952989211532,-77.0408773125522 38.9953191900249))
```

Postgis 2.2

```
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
```

How would I properly upgrade my spatial database?

Comment: The first one is the [EWKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) notation and the second one ist the [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) notation of the same geometry. A geometry column in postgis always contains geometries in WKB format, in both postgis 1.5 and 2.2. I think, your upgraded database looks fine.

Comment: When I run queries against the Postgis 2.2 value, I receive `- parse error at position 16 within geometry`

Comment: I cannot see where the parse error is raised, or anything else of concern with the upgrade. However, consider using SRID=4326 rather than the non-standard values (i.e. SRID=900914 is not used by anyone).

Comment: If you are getting parse errors for a query, you should post that query. @TommasoDiBucchianico your comment is worthy of being an answer.

Comment: 900914 seems like a typo of 900913 the GOOGLE (in leech) web mercator projection which is deprecated and is the_same_ as 3857. for more details see this question:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/what-is-the-difference-between-epsg900913-and-epsg3857